# Badminton, double hit by one player, new rules?

Tags: rules, badminton

What are the rules that apply when a player makes a double hit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a foul if the player hits the shuttlecock twice in row, except in the case it touches the racket head and the strings in the same shot.

> 13.3.8 is hit twice in succession by the same player. However, a shuttle hitting the head and the stringed area of the racket in one
>   stroke shall not be a "fault";

Source (in French, sorry : http://www.badminton-web.fr/badminton/regles-badminton.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have an additional question, namely: what if the player hits the shuttlecock firstly by throat or shaft and then by the stringed area?

Comment: I think this is a foul.

Comment: But you are not sure, right?

Comment: The exception I pointed out in the only one I found, so I'm not 100% sure but logically, this is a foul.

Comment: I met some players, who are claiming that it is not a foul. This is the reason why I am asking about details.

Comment: Maybe they include all the body (except the strings) and not just the racket head... 
But I jusk looked at the official rules and this is a foul : `13.3.8 is hit twice in succession by the same player. However, a shuttle hitting the head and the stringed area of the racket in one stroke shall not be a "fault";`
And the head is connected to the shaft by the throat, so it's not the same thing... Thus, definitely a foul.

Comment: OK, let's wait and see, maybe answers will be added.

Comment: it's definitely a fault. let your players read the rules :)

Comment: Updated link to the regulations: https://system.bwfbadminton.com/documents/folder_1_81/Regulations/Laws/Part%20II%20Section%201A%20-%20Laws%20of%20Badminton%20-%20June%202016%20Revised%202.pdf

Answer (score 5):

According the official *[LAWS OF BADMINTON](https://system.bwfbadminton.com/documents/folder_1_81/Regulations/Laws/Part%20II%20Section%201A%20-%20Laws%20of%20Badminton%20-%20June%202016%20Revised%202.pdf)*, set by the [Badminton World Federation](https://bwfbadminton.com/), chapter 13 is affected: *FAULTS*. Here the different situations are outlined when it is considered a 'fault' and in paragraph 13.3.8 the [following about that is mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzGri.png):

> **13. FAULTS**
>
> It shall be a 'fault':
>
> ...
>
> - 13.3 If in play, the shuttle:
>
>   - ...
>   - 13.3.8 is hit twice in succession by the same player. However, a shuttle hitting the head and the stringed area of the racket in one stroke shall not be a 'fault'.